# Div Id="chartcontainer" Overriding Width Of Page

Tags: html, css

I've been working on my website again, but have come across this very bizarre issue. Most of the chartcontainer's adjust to the width of the web page. However, the top 2 are being overridden by what looks like the element.style attribute as shown here: 
[image]

This means that when the web page is first loaded: http://newton-poppleford-weather.co.uk/trends.htm, the width of the top 2 charts are wider than what the page allows for (100%).

I've tried to code style specific HTML after the 'div id="containerx"' to try and override it but that doesn't work. For example:

```
<div id="chartcontainer1" style="width: 100% !important">
```

I'm not sure how/if I can edit the element.style code as after researching it seems that this is set in stone.

Thanks for your help.

William

Comment: If anything is set by element.style that means that the element has CSS inline with the HTML. This is usually added by JavaScript plugins etc.

Comment: I thought so, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add css this way

```
#chartcontainer1 {width:100% !important;}
```

Comment: Thanks. Would I add this directly to the page or via one of the declared css files?

Comment: you declared to css file or page head with style tag

Comment: Thanks. I found it was to with missing ":" in the javascript code declared in the page.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for the horizontal scroll is that you have a 100% wide content and additional padding on left and right here:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 120px;
}
```

Change it and leave out the left and right padding to:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Ideally, I'd like the padding as then the page table will be the width of the whole page which doesn't look exactly brilliant. Is this the only way I can get around this?

Comment: What I can't understand is why 2 of them are wider than the rest.